# why values in bigquery showing null while they aren't?

Tags: google-bigquery

, I have downloaded a dataset as csv, and now I am working on google bigquery. So I uploaded dataset into it,but it shows null values for half of the columns

i tried changing options in advanced section while creating table but still same result